# Libreoffice footnote font color

Tags: libreoffice

I want to copy/paste into a footnote and adjust the formatting to fit the default footnote formatting. It's a grey-ish colour not the black color used for text. Can't find it in the available text colors. How do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the help of libreoffice, you can find in the index under "colors:adding" a description of how to add a new color to the color pallets.